# How do I add this text to my xml file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This code is in my OnCreate() function.I got this code online and I need to make some changes to it in my xml file like add background properties and other design elements etc. , please help as to how I can transfer it in my activity_main.xml file without any errors(This is where I'll work on the design portion).
Thank you in advance.

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
//RecordButton is a class I created and mRecordButton is an object which
// inherits some porperties of it.
//Same with PlayButton and mPlayButton
    ll.addView(mRecordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    0));
    mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
    ll.addView(mPlayButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    0));
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.yourcompany.package.RecordButton
         android:id="@+id/record_btn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <com.yourcompany.package.PlayButton
         android:id="@+id/play_btn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout/>
```

Then in that same onCreate() method, remove the existing code and use setContentView(R.layout.layout_name)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the input. The RecordButton and PlayButton classes are declared in MainActivity and I have given the statement as <com.mycompany.package.MainActivity.RecordButton../>.But it gives me a Rendering Error and says the classes could not be found. What might be the reason for that?

Comment: Are those classes public?  Either way, I would recommend putting those classes in their own files.

Comment: Youre right,I created them in separate classes. But the new Class I created goes like:public class RecordButton extends Button. Now I need it to extend View as well. I know public class RecordButton extends Button,View is not possible.Can you suggest what I should do? if you know how the same can be done with interface or something that would be just great! Thanks

Comment: Button already extends from View - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html